# Change elements in a CvSeq in python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to extract contours from an image, rotate these contours and insert them in a new image. The code is given below. 
My problem is in the rotate contours method. When the code is executed the following error is seen "TypeError: 'cv.cvseq' object does not support item assignment".

Any ideas of how to solve this problem? I'm using python bindings for Opencv 2.2.

```
import cv

def rotateContour(contour, centerOfMass, angle):
    for index in range(0, len(contour)):
        contour[index] = rotatePoint(contour[index], centerOfMass, angle)   
    return contour

def rotatePoint(point, centerOfMass, angle):
    px, py = point
    x, y = centerOfMass
    temppoint = (px-x, py-y)
    temppointx = temppoint[0]*math.cos(angle) + temppoint[1] * math.sin(angle)
    temppointy = temppoint[1]*math.cos(angle) - temppoint[0] * math.sin(angle)
    temppoint = (temppointx + x, temppointy + y)

    return temppoint

inputimage = cv.LoadImage('filename.png', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
outputimage = cv.CreateImage((10000, 300), 8, 1)

storage = cv.CreateMemStorage (0)
contours = cv.FindContours(inputimage, storage, cv.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contour_iterator(contours):
    gray = cv.CV_RGB(200, 200, 200)
    # Rotate contour somehow
    contour = rotatecontour(contour)
    cv.DrawContours(outputimage, contour, gray, gray, 0, -1, 8)

cv.SaveImage("outputfile.png", outputimage)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can’t change the elements of the `cvseq` object using the Python bindings (notice [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_dynamic_structures.html) that list of Python methods for manipulating `cvseq` objects only has methods for removing sequence elements and changing their order.)

The Python bindings do nonetheless provide the tools to achieve your stated aim of rotating the contours in an image.

Since the `cv.DrawContours()` method requires a `cvseq` as input, we have to find some other way of drawing contours after storing and manipulating them in Python. One way to do this is by using the `cv.FillPoly()` or `cv.DrawPoly()` methods (which take a list of lists of tuples as input) depending whether the thickness parameter that would have been passed to `cv.DrawContours()` is -1 or > 0 respectively.

So, one way to find contours and draw their rotated counterparts, would be as follows (where the centre of mass of each contour is found by redrawing in filled form and using OpenCV’s moment functions):

```
import cv
import numpy as np

# Draw contour from list of tuples.
def draw_contour( im , contour , color , thickness = 1 , linetype = 8 ,
                  shift = 0 ) :
  if thickness == -1 :
    cv.FillPoly( im , [contour] , color , linetype , shift )
  else :
    cv.PolyLine( im , [contour] , True , color , thickness , linetype , shift )

# Rotate contour around centre point using numpy.
def rotate_contour( contour , centre_point , theta ) :
  rotation = np.array( [ [ np.cos( theta ) , -np.sin( theta ) ] , 
                         [ np.sin( theta ) ,  np.cos( theta ) ] ] )
  centre = np.vstack( [ centre_point ] * len( contour ) )
  contour = np.vstack( contour ) - centre
  contour = np.dot( contour , rotation ) + centre
  return [ tuple ( each_row ) for each_row in contour ]

# Find centre of mass by drawing contour in closed form and using moments.
def find_centre_of_mass( contour ) :
  bottom_right = np.max( contour , axis = 0 )
  blank = cv.CreateImage( tuple ( bottom_right ) , 8 , 1 )
  cv.Set( blank , 0 )
  draw_contour( blank , contour , 1, -1 )
  moments = cv.Moments( blank , 1 )  
  sM00 = float ( cv.GetSpatialMoment( moments , 0 , 0 ) )
  sM01 = float ( cv.GetSpatialMoment( moments , 0 , 1 ) )
  sM10 = float ( cv.GetSpatialMoment( moments , 1 , 0 ) )
  return ( sM10 / sM00 , sM01 / sM00 )

THETA = np.pi / 3.0
COLOR = cv.CV_RGB( 200 , 200 , 200 )
input_image = cv.LoadImage( ‘filename.png’ , cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE )
output_image = cv.CreateImage( ( input_image.width , input_image.height ) , 
                                 input_image.depth , input_image.nChannels )
cv.Set( output_image , 0 )

storage = cv.CreateMemStorage( 0 )
contour_pointer = cv.FindContours( input_image , storage , 
                                   cv.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL , 
                                   cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )

while contour_pointer is not None :
  contour = contour_pointer [ : ]
  centre_of_mass = find_centre_of_mass( contour )
  rotated_contour = rotate_contour( contour , centre_of_mass , THETA )
  draw_contour( output_image , rotated_contour , COLOR , -1 )
  contour_pointer = contour_pointer.h_next()

cv.SaveImage( ‘outputfile.png’ , output_image)
```